# is stat(2) read-after-write consistent with write(2)?

Tags: filesystems, linux-kernel, posix, system-calls, file-metadata

`man 2 write` states:

> POSIX requires that a read(2) that can be proved to occur after a write() has returned will return the new data. Note that not all filesystems are POSIX conforming.

In Linux, is this also true for `stat(2)` and `fstat(2)`, in particular, for the `stat.st_size` member?
Specifically, if you open a file with `O_CREAT`, successfully write 948427 bytes to it, then either stat or fstat it, are you guaranteed to see a `st_size` of 948427?
(If so, is this a guarantee for POSIX filesystems, or something that typical Linux filesystems provide in practice, or a property of certain filesystems and not others?)

Comment: I would be very, _very_ surprised if any one of the usual general purpose _local_ FSs wouldn't be able to keep track of the file size after a `write()` to be able to return it with `stat()`. The OS needs to know the file size at least to allocate data blocks and to put append-mode writes in the correct position anyway. Now, NFS and such remote filesystems could be different, as all the data isn't available locally. I don't know if `stat()` goes to the server on NFS, but AFAIU, reads in general _don't_, so in the case of multiple clients writing, the read-after-write guarantees might not hold.

Answer (score -1):

`stat` retrieves the `st_size` as well as other informations (metadata) from the [**inode**](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html) :

> …Each file has an inode containing metadata about the file. An
> application can retrieve this metadata using stat(2) (or related
> calls), which returns a stat structure…

So everything boils down to the question : When will the inode be updated following a successful `write` ? it can be :

**Synchronously** : The metadata is commited in sync with the data, before `write` returns

- per-file using the **O_SYNC** flag when [open](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)-ing the file

> By the time write(2) (or similar) returns, the output data and
> associated file metadata have been transferred to the underlying
> hardware

- per-filesystem: (only honored by ext2, ext3, fat, vfat and ufs) adding the **sync** option to [mount](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) (or in `/etc/fstab`)
- per-file and [exclusively in the case of an ext2 underlying file-system](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ext2.txt) by setting the **S attribute** of the file [`chattr +S`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chattr.1.html)

> When a file with the 'S' attribute set is modified, the changes are
> written synchronously to the disk; this is equivalent to the 'sync'
> mount option applied to a subset of the files.

In these cases of synchronous updates, yes, `stat` requested after some `write` will reflect changes made.

**Asynchronously :** The commit of the metadata is not triggered by data changes, the default… in which case, whatever the (modern) filesystem, a consecutive stat will reflect changes only… per pure chance…

Comment: The last part is incorrect. Even if the data hasn't been flushed to the disk, the metadata is stored in buffer cache. The kernel will serve `stat` calls from its internal structure and thus on POSIX filesystems it will **always** be up to date. The only exception is if the machine had cold boot before data was synced, and after boot the inode will not include the latest writes.

Comment: @aviro : I'm possibly missing something. Whatever the FS, the st_size might be extracted from the inode cache. And the kernel offers no guarantee that when write returns the inode cache has been updated. (Some experiences proves this with EXT4 but OK, I agree, EXT4 is not fully POSIX.)

Comment: Pay attention again to the quote in the question about the POSIX requirement. It's very clear. It requires that `stat` after `write` on POSIX compliant filesystems will return the updated data. It doesn't say anthing about sync/async. The implementation of most filesystems are in the kernel, and in order for them to be POSIX compliant they **absolutely** guarantee that this requirement is fulfilled, by any means necessary, regardless if the data is written to the disk or not. Not all filesystems are POSIX compliant (see NFS, for instance), but those who are absolutely guarantee this behavior.

Comment: By the way, what makes you think EXT4 is not POSIX compliant?

Comment: @aviro : Thx for your deeper comment #3. I'll investigate more formally into the POSIX requirement. For what concerns your last question, OK… the experiment is a bit old and things might have changed since… anyway : https://github.com/boltdb/bolt/issues/284

Comment: I'm pretty sure the boltdb issue is a red herring: it's about ACID compliance under power cut, but the question here is about the behavior on a running system, not about durability.